# Fluent wait vs WebDriver wait

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am confused between `FluentWait` and `WebDriverWait`.

`FluentWait` and `WebDriverwait` both uses the same features like ignoring exceptions, change polling time interval, expected conditions etc.

As per my understanding both implements the `Wait` interface. Additionally `WebDriverWait` extends `FluentWait` (which means all the functionalities are present also in `WebDriverWait`).

What are the extra features `WebDriverWait` holds that are not present in `FluentWait`?

Answer (score 8):

FluentWait and WebDriverWait both are the implementations of Wait interface.

The goal to use Fluent WebDriver Explicit Wait and WebDriver Explicit Wait is more or less same. However, in few cases, FluentWait can be more flexible. Since both the classes are the implementations of same Wait interface so more or less both have the same feature except **The FluentWait has a feature to accept a predicate or a function as an argument in until method**. On the other hand, **WebDriverWait accepts only function as an [ExpectedCondition](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedCondition.html) in until method** which restricts you to use a boolean return only.When you use Predicate in FluentWait, it allows you to return any Object from until method.

Look at here carefully: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html#until-com.google.common.base.Predicate-

Examples:
A FluentWait having Function as an argument in until with String return:

```
public void exampleOfFluentWait() {
        WebElement foo = driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
        new FluentWait<WebElement>(foo)
            .withTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .until(new Function<WebElement, String>() {
                        @Override
                        public String apply(WebElement element) {
                            return element.getText();
                        }
                    });
    }
```

The Same FluentWait having Function with Boolean return as an argument in until method.

```
public void exampleOfFluentWait() {
            WebElement foo = driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
            new FluentWait<WebElement>(foo)
                .withTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .until(new Function<WebElement, Boolean>() {
                            @Override
                            public Boolean apply(WebElement element) {
                                return element.getText().contains("foo");
                            }
                        });
        }
```

One more FluentWait with Predicate.

```
public void exampleOfFluentWithPredicate() {
    WebElement foo = driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
    new FluentWait<WebElement>(foo)
        .withTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .pollingEvery(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .until(new Predicate<WebElement>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean apply(WebElement element) {
                        return element.getText().endsWith("04");
                    }
                });
}
```

Example of WebDriverWait:

```
public void exampleOfWebDriverWait() {
        WebElement foo = driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));

        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        .pollingEvery(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .withTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(foo));
    }
```

Comment: You can also use and define polling time in WebDriverWait.

Comment: @DeepakKakkarHave changed my answer.

Comment: @PriyanshuShekhar I am little skeptical with your answer, I think predicate does not support `apply()` method, it should be `test()` method. Secondly, predicate only returns **boolean** value but you mentioned it will return any **object**. Can you please clarify a bit on this?

Comment: @priyanshu, until method accepts Function<> parameter only. Predicate cant be used. wait interface has only one method - until(Function<T,K>)

Answer (score 8):

There is actually very little difference between two. According to `WebDriverWait` source code it says:

> It will ignore instances of `NotFoundException` that are encountered
>   (thrown) by default in the `until` condition, and immediately
>   propagate all others.  You can add more to the ignore list by
>   calling `ignoring(exceptions to add)`

The only difference is that by default element not found exception is ignored in `WebDriverWait`. The rest of features is all exactly the same with `FluentWait` since `WebDriverWait` extends it.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that in a Webdriver wait we cannot perform pooling for wait scenario where as in Fluent wait, we can set pooling time which isn't possible in Webdriver wait.

**Webdriver wait example**

```
WebElement dynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("dynamicElement")));
```

**Fluent wait example**
Below code is to wait 30 seconds for an element to be present on the page, checking for its presence once every 5 seconds.

```
 Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
        .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
        .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

    WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() 
    {   
      public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
      driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));    
    }
    });
```

Comment: Polling time is possible in both waits.

Answer (score 0):

In FluentWait, The polling period is controlled, whereas in Explicilit wait it is 250 ms.

The user also has the flexibility to ignore exceptions that may occur during the polling period using the IgnoreExceptionTypes command.

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/@ahamedabdulrahman/differences-between-fluentwait-and-webdriverwait-explicit-wait-7adc2d68935d

FluentWait is general purpose wait whereas ExplicitWait is typed to WebDriver and ignores NoElementException by default. FluentWait can be used with any type including WebDriver too. WebDriverWait can only be used with WebDriver.

Apart from that both can use pollingEvery(), ignoring() etc.